# SQL/MySQL: get only some columns as distinct in query with joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my MySQL database I have the following tables:

**recipes** (=ricette) which contains the id of the recipe and some basic info

**ingredients** (=ingredienti) which as got as many rows as many ingredients there are in that recipe, and finally the table

**recipe_kind** (=tiporicetta) which contains the id of the recipe and the kind of the recipe.

I would like to get all the ingredients of a recipe and so I perform:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.nome,
    r.descrizione,
    r.persone,
    t.tipo,
    c.cibo,
    i.quantita,
    i.unitamisura_id
FROM
    ricette AS r
        LEFT JOIN
    ingredienti AS i ON i.ricette_id = r.id
        LEFT JOIN
    cibo AS c ON c.id = i.cibo_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tiporicetta AS t ON t.id = r.tiporicetta_id
WHERE
    (r.id = '52')
```

but with that query I get the name, description, people and kind many times, once for each row. Instead, I would like to have nome, descrizione, persone and tipo only once and then the list of the ingredients.
How can I do that with an unique query?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`, with `group_concat`.

Comment: To my way of thinking, and to a rough approximation, there is NO problem in MySQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution. Instead, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You're trying to solve a display issue in SQL. Instead, let your display tier handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    r.nome,
    r.descrizione,
    r.persone,
    "", "", "", ""
FROM ricette AS r
WHERE 
    (r.id = '52')

UNION

SELECT
    "", "", ""
    t.tipo,
    c.cibo,
    i.quantita,
    i.unitamisura_id
FROM
    ricette AS r LEFT JOIN
    ingredienti AS i ON i.ricette_id = r.id LEFT JOIN
    cibo AS c ON c.id = i.cibo_id LEFT JOIN
    tiporicetta AS t ON t.id = r.tiporicetta_id
WHERE
    (r.id = '52')
```